# Почему в mysql столько много кодировок - кодировка клиента, соединения, базы данных.....?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Запутался в кодировках mysql.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему столько много кодировок - кодировка клиента, соединения, базы данных.....? Ведь кодировка - это "как прочитать существующий текстовый файл" и "как записать символы нового текстового файла".

**Зачем столько раз указывать кодировку, что за что отвечает,и что это вообще за переменные (я их не объявлял)?** В `PHP` или в `JavaScript`, например, переменная появляется только тогда, когда ее ОБЪЯВЛЯЕШЬ(var x=10; или @y=20;).

Comment: Вопрос вроде и интересный, но надо просто вспомнить, что разработка может вестись разными компаниями, разных стран мира и разными ОС, наразном железе для разных клиентов. И кто-то может это всё комбинировать в своей работе. Может клиент в китае, сидит на винде, соединяется с США с сервером на SkyNetOS, с БД которую поставляют Индусы из секретного офиса

Comment: SkyNet - прямо как в Терминаторе2)

Answer (score 1):

затем, чтобы знать в какой кодировке клиент отправляет данные, в какой их записывать, в какой отдавать, в какой сравнивать, какую использовать, если клиент ничего не сообщает и т.д.
в доке это все подробно описано

Comment: я не понимаю, кто такой "клиент". говорится, что это та программа, которая общается с сервером, например, mysql. если через пхп обращаться, то пхп-интерпретатор-это клиент? а если через mysql monitor, то mysql monitor - это клиент?

Comment: да, та программа, которая посылает запросы серверу